# When to use know and knows

Tags: grammar

I'm confused in whether to write know or knows in the following statement:-
"The ones who are included know better."?

Also explain the difference between the two, thanks.

Comment: You may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. To understand which site you should use, read [this discussion](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell) on Meta. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: FWIW: there are two rules at work here: (1) for regular verbs, only the third person *singular* takes the -s form (e.g. *he knows*); (2) the verb number must agree with the subject number. Since the subject here ("ones") is plural, we use third person plural: "[they] *know*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is very basic, I think you should've just googled it. But here's the answer:

It is the same as any other verb, we put an 's' at the end when we're talking about a singular noun, e.g. drink: He **drinks** coffee every morning; They **drink** too much when they get together on weekends.

Therefore, since 'ones' is plural, we use **know**: "The ones who are included know better".

Hope this helps.

Comment: More precisely, it's the 3rd person singular subject that takes that form of the verb -- I know, you know, he knows.

Answer (score 0):

You can exactly say:

> The **ones** who are
>   included **know** better."

because "ones" is plural, which suggests more than one individuals.

If you think that you should use "know" then you have to start the given sentence as "the one ..." because "one" is singular, after which "knows" is acceptable, such as:

> The **one** who **is**
>   included **knows** better."

Comment: You can kind of view it as conservation of `s` characters.